# What's the package name in django for urlfetch

Tags: python, django

Which package is used to import for same work in django, what we do with from google.appengine.api import urlfetch in google app engine...

Answer (score 1):

[urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)

Answer (score 1):

[urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html)(Open arbitrary resources by URL), [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)(extensible library for opening URLs)

These are python libraries and not django packages.